# getting Android 12 Tablet Blackview Tab 7 Pro unique name

Tags: javascript, android, ipad, tablet

So i have a web base attendance form that when the employee scans there ID it auto fills user and action and time what i want to do is add a workcentre to this form and whenever the user sign in on lets say on line 1 workcentre A it will say User:2194 action:clock in Time: 8:00 AM and workcentre:A but i need it to know which ipad is for which workcentre. So what i did i for each Android 12 Tablet Blackview Tab 7 Pro is i have changed the device name to fit each line and workcentre so for example device name for line 1 workcentre A would be L1WA. Also this information has to be passed through idempiere and only using JavaScript

(note: we have work centre ranging from a-z)

Does anyone know a way on how to do this through JS ive tried grabbing the mac address but its too complex to do.

i need it to do this

User:2194
action:clock in
time:8:00:00 AM
Workcentre:A